# Samsung KNOX LICENSE_STATUS not broadcasted

Tags: android, android-manifest, samsung-knox

I use the latest (3.4.1) version of the KNOX libraries, and trying to activate my license.

My AndroidManifest entry:

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.KnoxLicenseReceiver"
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.samsung.android.knox.intent.action.LICENSE_STATUS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And activating the license like this:

```
KnoxEnterpriseLicenseManager
                .getInstance(context)
                .activateLicense(context.getString(R.string.const_kpe_key), getPackageName.exec())
```

It shows the Toast that the license was activated successfully (and works fine — I can, for example, disable the camera), but the receiver is never called.

I've tried on multiple devices with different Android versions (5.1 and 7.1) with no luck. What's wrong?

Comment: have you read throught the LogCat to see if Knox sends out a broadcast & if so how it differs from your receiver

Comment: @Blundell `adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts history | grep LICENSE_STATUS` does not show anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Samsung docs are not correct. Correct intent action is

```
com.samsung.android.knox.intent.action.KNOX_LICENSE_STATUS
```

while action in docs is

```
com.samsung.android.knox.intent.action.LICENSE_STATUS
```

Comment: It seems like the differentiator is whether you use KnoxEnterpriseLicenseManager or EnterpriseDeviceManager. Which depends on what type of license you want to activate. I guess they have many types and they might keep changing it but for simplification it might be either ELM(EnterpriseDeviceManager) or KPE(KnoxEnterpriseLicenseManager) license.
https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/license/KnoxEnterpriseLicenseManager.html
https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/license/EnterpriseLicenseManager.html